# How to fetch the json column data from database in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, open-json

I have created a small demo app using .NET 6 with EF core and I am using Serilog to log exceptions into my database.

Everything is working fine but now I want to display the log table details on my view (cshtml).
Current log table columns are:

- Message
- MessageTemplate
- Level
- TimeStamp
- Exception
- **LogEvent**
- ClientIP

I have created a stored procedure to fetch the log details but the LogEvent column contains json data like below:

```json
{
   "TimeStamp":"2022-07-23T20:00:55.6987337",
   "Level":"Information",
   "Message":"Started executing Privacy",
   "MessageTemplate":"Started executing Privacy",
   "Properties":{
      "ActionId":"ba7d94ab-3758-4a4c-a3ef-2bda514a531c",
      "ActionName":"Serilog_Demo.Controllers.HomeController.Privacy (Serilog_Demo)",
      "RequestId":"SomeRequest",
      "RequestPath":"/Home/Privacy",
      "ConnectionId":"something",
      "MachineName":"Test"
   }
}
```

My goal is to get "Message","TimeStamp","ClientIP", ActionName","MachinName","RequestPath" from above json object. How do I do that? I followed this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)

Which shows how to get the JSON data but it seems like I am making some mistake in fetching the records.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspGetApplicationLogs
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT ClientIP, LogEvent 
    FROM ApplicationLogs 
    ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC;

     -- this code is not working for me
    DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @json = (SELECT LogEvent FROM ApplicationLogs)

    SELECT *
    FROM OPENJSON((SELECT TOP 1 LogEvent FROM ApplicationLogs))
    WITH (logDateTime timestamp '$.TimeStamp',
          level nvarchar(255) '$.Level',
          ActionName NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.Properties.ActionName');
END
```

And here is my table script, in case if anybody needs it.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ApplicationLogs]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Message] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [MessageTemplate] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Level] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [TimeStamp] [datetime] NULL,
    [Exception] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [LogEvent] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ClientIP] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ClientAgent] [nvarchar](max) NULL
)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[ApplicationLogs] ON 
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ApplicationLogs] ([Id], [Message], [MessageTemplate], [Level], [TimeStamp], [Exception], [LogEvent], [ClientIP], [UserName], [ClientAgent]) 
VALUES (1, N'Started executing Privacy', N'Started executing Privacy', N'Information', CAST(N'2022-07-23T20:00:55.700' AS DateTime), NULL, N'{"TimeStamp":"2022-07-23T20:00:55.6987337","Level":"Information","Message":"Started executing Privacy","MessageTemplate":"Started executing Privacy","Properties":{"ActionId":"ba7d94ab-3758-4a4c-a3ef-2bda514a531c","ActionName":"Serilog_Demo.Controllers.HomeController.Privacy (Serilog_Demo)","RequestId":"0E:00000004","RequestPath":"/Home/Privacy","ConnectionId":"SomeConnection","MachineName":"Test"}}', NULL, NULL, NULL)
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ApplicationLogs] ([Id], [Message], [MessageTemplate], [Level], [TimeStamp], [Exception], [LogEvent], [ClientIP], [UserName], [ClientAgent]) 
VALUES (2, N'Attempted to divide by zero.', N'Attempted to divide by zero.', N'Error', CAST(N'2022-07-23T20:00:55.803' AS DateTime), N'System.DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero.
   at Serilog_Demo.Controllers.HomeController.Privacy() in \Sol_Serilog_Demo\Serilog_Demo\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 24', N'{"TimeStamp":"2022-07-23T20:00:55.8034293","Level":"Error","Message":"Attempted to divide by zero.","MessageTemplate":"Attempted to divide by zero.","Exception":"System.DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero.\r\n   at Serilog_Demo.Controllers.HomeController.Privacy() in \Sol_Serilog_Demo\\Serilog_Demo\\Controllers\\HomeController.cs:line 24","Properties":{"ActionId":"ba7d94ab-3758-4a4c-a3ef-2bda514a531c","ActionName":"Serilog_Demo.Controllers.HomeController.Privacy (Serilog_Demo)","RequestId":"4","RequestPath":"/Home/Privacy","ConnectionId":"VIB38TE","MachineName":"Test"}}', NULL, NULL, NULL)
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[ApplicationLogs] OFF
GO
```

I do not want to deserialize the LogEvent column data at .net end. Can anybody help to parse the JSON and get the log event value from my database?

Comment: Note that a `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` is a sure sign of a flaw. This means that the data engine is free to return what ever arbitrary row(s) it wants, and the row(s) could be different every time you run said query. If you are using `TOP` you need to ensure the query has an `ORDER BY` so that you get consistent and reliable results. Your subquery `(select top 1  LogEvent from ApplicationLogs)` is quite likely to give you very arbitrary (and inconsistent) results.

Comment: Also, are all your columns *really* likely to have more than 4,000 characters in them? I don't think any IP standard issues IP addresses that are over 4,000 characters in length, and giving someone the choice to have a username that is up to **1 billion** characters in length seems a bit silly, if I am honest.

Comment: @Larnu thank you for your explanation. I will edit my question. But is there a way to get the json data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `CROSS APPLY` to feed the JSON column into `OPENJSON`

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE uspGetApplicationLogs
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT
  al.Message,
  al.ClientIP,
  al.LogEvent,
  al.TimeStamp,
  j.*  
FROM ApplicationLogs al
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(al.LogEvent)
  WITH (
    logDateTime datetime2 '$.TimeStamp',
    level nvarchar(255) '$.Level',
    RequestPath nvarchar(250) '$.Properties.RequestPath',
    MachineName nvarchar(250) '$.Properties.MachineName',
    ActionName nvarchar(250) '$.Properties.ActionName'
  ) j
ORDER BY al.TimeStamp DESC;
```

Comment: Hi @Charlieface, thank you for your answer but this query takes very long time to fetch 1000 records. Any thoughts on optimization?

Comment: Removing the `ORDER BY` would probably help. Remove any columns you don't need. Without seeing the execution plan I cannot help further